# Add a sub-routeunder the root but over all the controllers

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes

I have an ASP.NET MVC web application with the following routing system:

localhost:20119

- HomeController
- AnotherController
- ThridController

And I want to modify it so that there is one more subroute/directory that "contains" all of the routes, such as:

localhost:20119

- AppName

  - HomeController
  - AnotherController
  - ThridController

So instead of going to the following URL:

> http://localhost:20119/Home/Index

Users will instead go to

> http://localhost:20119/AppName/Home/Index

I am using:

- Visual Studio 2012 
  -.NET 4.5

and I believe MVC 4:

```
<dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
```

These are my configurations:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should just be able to add another layer to the routes in RouteConfig.cs.  For example, you could do something like:

```
routes.MapRoute(
  name: "Default",
  url: "AppName/{controller}/{action}",
  defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to bind the routing scheme to a physical directory location, there is an open source project that does just that called [MvcCodeRouting](https://github.com/maxtoroq/MvcCodeRouting) (available on [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MvcCodeRouting/)). There is nothing built into MVC that correlates routes with a physical directory location, but MVC can be extended to do it as in that project.